# Python comparison weirdness

Tags: python, boolean-operations

I have an object that I need to compare some attributes of and I can't explain what is going on, but the following is the output of my VS code debugger (I added '=' before each output)

```
(0 > 55000 | 150 > 280)
=False # expected
250>150
=True # expected
True & False 
=False # expected
(250>150 & (0 > 55000 | 150 > 280))
=True # what????
```

Comment: Boolean OR is `or`, not `|`.

Comment: Same with `and` and `&`.

Comment: (If you're used to NumPy and Pandas using `|` and `&`, that's because `or` and `and` are non-overloadable due to short circuiting issues.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For numbers, `&` is "bitwise and" and `|` is "bitwise or". These operators have higher precedence than comparison operators like `>` and `<`.

`150 & (0 > 55000 | 150 > 280)` == `150 & 0` == `0`
then `150>0` is `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using [binary bitwise operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) `&` and `|`.
You should be using [boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 0):

| and & are bit operators. bit operators have higher priority better than comparison operator. you should change '|' to "or"and '&' to "and"